# How can I change my text size depending on the HEIGHT of the div?

Tags: html, css, text, size

I can change my text size depending on the width of my div, but not on the height. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A perfect css3 solution for you.

set all your font-sizes and line-height on 'vw' values .

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Here is a link to article. 
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units